# Is sendBroadcast() required for a PendingIntent with an Intent for a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, location-services

My app requires regular updates of the user's location, in order to display them on a **GoogleMap** .

To achieve this I am using the  **LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()** method, with the results being sent to a specified **PendingIntent**.

The **Intent** of the **PendingIntent** is a **BroadcastReceiver**, whose **onReceive()** method will process the results.

My question is: Do I need to invoke **sendBroadcast()** somewhere in order for the results to be received by the broadcast receiver, and if so, where?

Or, is it sufficient to have the **PendingIntent** with an **Intent** to a **BroadcastReceiver** for the results to get where they need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to invoke sendBroadcast() somewhere in order for the results to be received by the broadcast receiver, and if so, where?

No, you don't have to do that.

If you look at the javadoc for `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` you will see

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, **like calling Context.sendBroadcast()**.

---

> Or, is it sufficient to have the PendingIntent with an Intent to a BroadcastReceiver for the results to get where they need to?

Yes, that is enough, but note that you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.